# Filter questions by using both newest and votes filters, at the same time

Tags: feature-request, search

If you are filter the question order by newest you can get the most recent and if you filter them by votes, you will get most voted questions.

And when I am taking a look at the most voted questions, some of them are really old, and the answer is really clear for every novice in that field because of the passage of time.

But If I want to get the most voted questions that recently had been asked, what do I need to do?

Is there any way to do this?

I think these kind of options are necessary when the website becomes older and older and bigger and bigger.

Comment: Thanks A Lot @Martijn Pieters,for editing my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this search criteria `is:q created:2014-08` and then sort by **votes**. It will show you all questions which were posted in August 2014 (current month) sorted by votes.

For example:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20created%3a2014-08
```

You can define your own **recent period** by adding a date range in the search. For further reference check the [Search Help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).